# Some text_field values can't be set in my form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Env: Rails 3.2 project

In a form view I have :

```
 <%= f.text_field :number_of_units, :value => 2 %>

 <%= f.text_field :price_in_cents, :value => 20 %>
```

The page rendered show correctly my number of unit with value = 2 ,  yet my price in cents show 'NaN' or blank

I have tried many things and it doesn't look like I am able to set a value for :price_in_cent or :currency in that form. Other fields work fine.

here the form in its entirety:

```
<%= form_for(@pricing, :html => {:class => "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
<fieldset>
    <legend><strong><%= @pricing.service.title %></strong> <%= I18n.t('pricing.title') %></legend>
    <%= render :partial => 'layouts/error_explanation', :locals => {:object => @pricing} %>

    <%= debug @pricing %>


      <%= f.text_field :service_id %><br/>

      <%= f.text_field :currency, :value => Money::Currency.table[:nok][:iso_code] %>

      <%= f.text_field :pricing_unit_id %>

      <%= f.text_field :number_of_units, :value => 2 %>

      <%= f.text_field :price_in_cents, :value => 200 %>


      <%= f.submit I18n.t('pricing.buttons.accept'), class: 'btn btn-success pull-right' %>


</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

This is also happening with my currency field. All other fields are assigned correctly.

If I hit the save button, I obsviouly get null value for currency and price_in_cents.

I tried adding attr_accessible for all field in my model by it didn't help.

Any reason why this happens?

GENERATED HTML seems correct and values are correct only price_in_cents and currency are blank on the screen (?):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/pricings" class="form-inline" id="new_pricing" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ljVdzc4UNYi/RKIUqmKNd7e/PNc89BcM8F7ZhX9ViJc="></div>
<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>Fish</strong> Prisnivå</legend>



    <pre class="debug_dump">--- !ruby/object:Pricing
attributes:
&nbsp; id: !!null 
&nbsp; creative_service_id: 46
&nbsp; price_in_cents: 150000
&nbsp; currency: NOK
&nbsp; pricing_unit_id: 4
&nbsp; number_of_units: 1
&nbsp; created_at: !!null 
&nbsp; updated_at: !!null 
</pre>


      <input id="pricing_creative_service_id" name="pricing[creative_service_id]" size="30" type="text" value="46"><br>

      <input id="pricing_currency" name="pricing[currency]" size="30" type="text" value="NOK">

      <input id="pricing_pricing_unit_id" name="pricing[pricing_unit_id]" size="30" type="text" value="4">

      <input id="pricing_number_of_units" name="pricing[number_of_units]" size="30" type="text" value="1">

      <input id="pricing_price_in_cents" name="pricing[price_in_cents]" size="30" type="text" value="150000">

      <input id="pricing_price" name="pricing[price]" type="hidden" value="NaN">

      <span style="font-size:24px;text-align:center;">Nybegynner: NOK 1500 pr.dag</span>

      <input class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="commit" type="submit" value="Jeg aksepterer prisbetingelsene">


</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you shouldn't assign value to a field bound to a member of your model.

You should set the default value in your controller's "new" action instead of setting it in the view.

I guess your model's value for the pricing_in_cents is nil.

Comment: Oh but I have done that. That actually where I had set the value in first place. Then since it was not working, I tried setting in the view. I should mention that in my question. This is very weird as other member do actually get set properly. Only Price in cent and currency remain nil. Thank for your reply though. I'll try harder on that direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.text_field :number_of_units, :value => 2 %><br>
<%= f.text_field :price_in_cents, :value => 20 %><br>


<%= f.text_field (:number_of_units, :value => 2 )%><br>
<%= f.text_field (:price_in_cents, :value => 20) %><br>
```

Hope this will help